# Identifying word strings and emoticons, trouble with punctuation

Tags: java, ios, sentiment-analysis

I am going to preface this by saying I have no technical experience in programming at all so please excuse me if I am using the incorrect terminology, but am still tasked to find a solution to a problem we have.

We have a portion of an app that is designed to identify positive and negative words and emoticons in Facebook and Twitter posts. We have developed comprehensive dictionaries for this however the code we have is not performing well.

The problem: words that end with punctuation (e.g. amazing!) are not being identified. As it stands words are split based on white space. I don' t think we can strip punctuation entirely as this will impact on identifying the lists of emoticons.

The solution: we hope is along these lines:
(1) split on white space to get words
Then, for each word:
    (i) check if they match any existing strings (e.g., “afraid”)
        (ia) if they do, go to the next word
        (ib) if they do not, remove punctuation from the tail of the word, then go back to (i).

Is anyone able to help me with the potential syntax for this? We need to write this for iPhone and Android (c++ and java?).
Any assistance is GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you already have a method (I'm calling it `checkDictionaryForMatches()`) to check whether a word matches one of the ones you have stored in your dictionary.

```
public static boolean[] checkString(String string){

    String[] stringarray = string.split(" ");
    boolean[] boolarray = new boolean[stringarray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringarray.length; i++){
        if (stringarray[i].checkDictionaryForMatches() == true){
            boolarray[i] = true;
        }
        else{
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(stringarray[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < sb.length(); j++){
                if (sb.charAt(j) == '!'){
                    sb.deleteCharAt(j);
                }
            }

            if (sb.toString().checkDictionaryForMatches() == true){
                boolarray[i] = true;
            }
            else{
                boolarray[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return boolarray;
}
```

This only gets rid of the `!` character, but if you want to use a more general solution you could simply use the `OR` operand (`||`) for each piece of punctuation, or preferably `RegEx`. Because the `checkDictionaryForMatches()` method is evaluated first, you can define all your emoticons as members of that dictionary. I'm on mobile, so I can't test it, but hopefully that will work.

This does leave you open to unexpected emoticons (@_@), but I don't know how you would deal with that. It also prevents the user from dropping punctuation into the middle of words (e.g. re.d or something random). Maybe it would be useful for stripping the `@` from Twitter handles, or something? Get back to me if there are any issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That has definitely helped us develop a solution. It was to: run a match on for all the emoticons in our dictionary on the sentence (no splitting); then to identify words: split on everything that isn't a-zA-Z0-9'. It does, however, have a small element of false positive matching (e.g. punctuation errors like this "I am writing a list of colours:Purple, green blue" = :P)